# Routing to new page in react

Tags: reactjs, google-api, react-router

I am trying to pass a parameter to a url which is provided by the on click event ,and use it to route to a different page.
Places autocomplete returns a list of suggested places and a event listener is attached to it such that whenever a user clicks on it ,It will direct the user to a new Page.
I have tried attaching Link from react-router to redirect the current page to the new location but I am unable to pass the  latitude and longitude as parameter

```
class Searchbar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { address: '' };
  }
 
  handleChange = address => {
    this.setState({ address });
  };
 
  handleSelect = address => {
    geocodeByAddress(address)
      .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
      .then(latLng => console.log('Success', latLng))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error', error));
  };
 
  render() {
    return (
      <PlacesAutocomplete
        value={this.state.address}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onSelect={this.handleSelect}
      >
        {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps, loading }) => (
          <div>
            <input
              {...getInputProps({
                placeholder: 'Search Places ...',
                className: 'location-search-input',
              })}
            />
            <div className="autocomplete-dropdown-container">
            
              {suggestions.map(suggestion => {
                const className = suggestion.active
                  ? 'suggestion-item--active'
                  : 'suggestion-item';
                // inline style for demonstration purpose
                const style = suggestion.active
                  ? { backgroundColor: '#fafafa', cursor: 'pointer' }
                  : { backgroundColor: '#ffffff', cursor: 'pointer' };
                return (
                  <div
                    {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, {
                      className,
                      style,
                    })}
                  >
                  <Link to=`/${pass latitude and long here}`> <span>{suggestion.description}</span></Link>    {//Not sure what to do here}
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </PlacesAutocomplete>
        );
      }
    }
    export default Searchbar
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead if using Link, redirect user whenever PlacesAutocomplete got onSelect event

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

//...
  handleSelect = address => {
    geocodeByAddress(address)
      .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
      .then(latLng => this.props.history.push(`/?lat=${latLng.lat}&?lat=${latLng.lng}`))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error', error));
  };
//...
export default withRouter(Searchbar)
```

Maybe you need to add loading indicator while `geocodeByAddress` still working